# Java Simple date format - dd/MM/yy v/s dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I need to parse a `String` into `dd/MM/YY hh:mm:ss` format.

Suppose if a `String` has value `09/06/17 05:59:59` then it should be parsed but if a `String` has value `09/06/2017 05:59:59` then this is also a valid format and getting parsed but in my requirement, a parse exception should be thrown for the later.

Code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line=" 09/06/17 05:59:59 20170609IT36701706080107 42 103 Output USD 970.20 IT3670";
        //String line=" 09/06/2017 05:59:59 20170609IT36701706080107 42 103 Output USD 970.20 IT3670";

        String dt=null;
        dt=line.substring(1, 19);

        SimpleDateFormat org_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YY hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat tgt_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        try {
              dt=line.substring(1, 19);

              System.out.println(dt);
              Date date = org_format.parse(dt);
              System.out.println(date);

              String tgt_date=tgt_format.format(date);
              System.out.println(tgt_date);
         } catch (ParseException e) {
              System.out.println(line);
         }
    }
}
```

Problem - In the code, uncommented line variable and commented line variable, both are giving result successfully. but the commented line should throw parsable exception as it's the pattern `dd/MM/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yy`.

`fmt.setLenient(false)` is not working.

I'm using Java 7. Don't have option to use Java 8 or later so can't use `java.time`.

Comment: and your code? can you please add it?

Comment: updated description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't have option to use java 8 or later so cant use java.time

The Java 8 date and time classes have been backported to Java 6 and 7, so yes, you can use them in your Java 7. Get [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). This is also the futureproof investment: if and when eventually you upgrade to Java 8 or 9, you will only have to modify your `import` declarations and your code will work with the `java.time` classes.

So I recommend you throw the outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` over the shoulder. It’s very typical for `SimpleDateFormat` to give you a result (very often an incorrect one) in a situation where you would want an exception. As you noted, sometimes `org_format.setLenient(false);` helps, but not in your case.

Using ThreeTen Backport:

```
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu HH:mm:ss");
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(1); // skip leading space
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(originalFormat.parse(line, pos));
```

This parses your line with 2-digit year into

```
2017-01-02 05:59:59
```

For the line with 4-digit year for which “in my requirement, parse exception should be thrown”, we get

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text ' 09/06/2017 05:59:59 20170609IT36701706080107 42 103 Output USD
>   ...' could not be parsed at index 9

It says index 9, that’s at the `17` in `2017`, that is, exactly where the third digit of the year is when there were only supposed to be two digits.

A couple of points to be aware of:

- Use capital `HH` in the format pattern for hour of day (small `hh` is for hour with AM or PM, only useful with an AM/PM marler). Use lowercase for the year, either `uu` or `yy` (not uppercase `YY`, it’s for weekbased year, only useful with a week number). BTW, again `SimpleDateFormat` let you get away with these bugs and *will* sometimes give you incorrect results; the modern classes will object by throwing an exception.
- My code will parse into a year from 2000 through 2099. Please check whether this is what you want. You may want to impose an additional restriction, for example, that the date-time should be in the past and not more than 5 years ago, for enhanced validation. You know better than I.

To convert into your target format:

```
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String targetDate = ldt.format(targetFormat);
```

With the former of your lines the result is

```
2017-01-02 05:59:59
```

Comment: thanks..really wanted to get rid of SimpeDateFormat. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to check if year contains 4 digits and if so throw new ParseException. The program is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String date = "09/06/17 05:59:59";

        if (date.matches("\\d{1,2}[/.-]\\d{1,2}[/.-]\\d{4} .*"))
            throw new ParseException("date has wrong format");
        else {

        }

    }
```

Comment: yes..regex can be one of the solution but i was trying to avoid regex here.

Comment: You can also split date string by `/` and check if third element startsWith 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match any of these date formats

```
String regex = "^(([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])/[1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("09/06/17 05:59:59");

if(matcher.matches()){
    //your next code
}
```